# Count paths with aggregate

Tags: powershell

I have a few files with list of full paths to files on the share drive.  For example:

```
\\server\share$\Public\HR\reports\report.doc
\\server\share$\Public\HR\reports\report.xls
```

I am trying to get a count of files per directory with aggregates to the top:

```
\\server\share$\Public:200
\\server\share$\Public\HR: 10
\\server\share$\Public\HR\reports: 2
```

So far I have:

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\FMU)
{
    foreach ($path in Get-Content $file)
    {
        while ($path -ne "")
        {
            $path = $path | Split-Path
            $array.$path.value, count++ #Not sure how to increment the count of the path value in the array
        }
    }
}
```

How do I set up an array to count all of the paths?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Group-Object` to get a count of of each path:

```
$paths = foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\FMU)) {
  foreach ($path in Get-Content $file){
    $path | Split-Path
  }
}

$grouped = $paths | Group-Object | select Count,Name

# outputs like:
Count Name                                                                                                
----- ----                                                                                                
   10 C:\folder1                                                                                
  200 C:\folder1\folder2\folder3                                                                
    3 C:\folder1\folder4
```

Edit: added doing a full aggregate as a second step.

```
# aggregate file counts as a second step
$aggregates = Foreach ($group in ($grouped|sort Name)) {

  # get sub-folders
  $children = $grouped | where { $_.Name -like ($group.Name+'\*') }

  # aggregate counts
  # count property can't be used because of count method name collision
  $group.Count = ($children|% count|measure -Sum).Sum + $group.count
  $group
}

$aggregates
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not aggregate up to the top.  c:\folder1 count should include everything in all of the subdirectories, so should be the highest number.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the Group-Object idea.  Here is what worked.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem C:\scripts\FMU)
{
    foreach ($path in Get-Content $file)
    {
        while ($path -ne "")
        {
            $path = $path | Split-Path
            $path
        }
    }
}
$paths | Group-Object | Select-Object Count, Name
```

Took a while, but it worked.

This could be modified to replace something like

```
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -Recurse) {Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File).Count}
```

Thanks